# JavaScript и вызов метода страницы

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Изучаю технологию клиент-серверных приложений и сайтов.
И дошел до ASP.NET и JavaScript.
Итак. Есть проект ASP.NET
Имеется CS_file.cs:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string[] GetPersonalInfo(int iParam_1, int iParam_2)
{
   //Some code
   return Rez;     
}
```

Имеется ASPXfile.aspx

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    //...
    function OnGetParam() 
    {
       int iPar1, iPar2;
       //Some code  
       CS_file.GetPersonalInfo(iPar1, iPar2, OnGetInfo); 
    }
    //...
    function OnGetInfo(result) 
    {
       //do something
    }
    //...
    //-->
    </script>
```

Тут вроде бы все понятно. JavaScript со стороны клиента вызывает метод на сервере без перегрузки страницы. (Поправьте если я не так понял)
Внимание вопрос. Каким образом OnGetInfo принимает и понимает что это результат работы метода на сервере? Что это за "магия" и где об этом почитать? Похожий пример тут: [тынц](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется callback функции или "функции обратного вызова", на них вся событийная модель JavaScript считай и построена. Если кратко, то браузер генерирует запрос и выполняет его, как только он получил ответ от сервера, он смотрит, какую функцию ему надо вызвать(ссылка на нее в третьем параметре GetPersonalInfo) и вызывает ее уже сам с передачей ей параметров.

Можешь почитать о технологии JavaScript под названием Ajax, которая как раз и используется.

Comment: Кстати внизу приведенного похожего примера как раз даются ссылки и упоминается ASP.NET Ajax.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение и наводку